# Regular Expression Regex Pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I am using Pig to process data.

My data looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MC><SC><S uid="1" gen="" art="Samsung" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music" alb="Samsung" ttl="Vacation"/><S uid="2" gen="" art="Samsung" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music" alb="Samsung" ttl="Mother earth"/><S uid="3" gen="" art="Samsung" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music" alb="Samsung" ttl="Over the horizon"/><S uid="4" gen="" art="Samsung" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music" alb="Samsung" ttl="Vocalise"/><S uid="5" gen="" art="Kitschi cupid" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music" alb="Samsung BeatDJ" ttl="Hard beat floor"/><S uid="6" gen="" yr="2011" art="David Kater" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music" alb="Samsung" ttl="Nothing left to say"/><S uid="7" gen="" art="Samsung" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music" alb="Samsung" ttl="Morning Dew"/><S uid="12" gen="" art="&lt;unknown&gt;" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/download" alb="download" ttl="mirzaghalib6_www.songs.pk_"/><S uid="13" gen="" art="&lt;unknown&gt;" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/download" alb="download" ttl="mirzaghalib7_www.songs.pk_"/><S uid="4555" gen="" yr="2012" art="Javed Ali &amp; Shakthisree Gopalan" cmp="Music: A.R. Rahman | Lyrics: Gulzar" fld="/mnt/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio" alb="Jab Tak Hai Jaan" ttl="Jab Tak Hai Jaan - www.Songs.PK"/></SC><PC/></MC>)
```

My goal is to parse it and save the entries in art=" " in HDFS interdependently.

I used the following PIG commands:

```
A= load 'smalltestdata' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);
data_split=FILTER C BY (line matches '.*art=.*');
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

To get only the information after `art="` and before `"` use the following regex:

```
(?<=art\=")(.*?)(?=")
```

Here is what is happening:

```
1. (?<=art\=") - This is a lookbehind.  It will look for matches after `art="`
2. (.*?)       - This is the search string that is returned.  The `?` makes it non-greedy, so it only grabs the least number of finds
3. (?=")       - This is a lookahead.  It will search for things before `"`
```

Lookbehinds and lookaheads are not returned, so the results will be all the text between `art="` and `"`.